# How can I redirect http to https?

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, https

I've installed ssl on both my pure-domain and `www` subdomain. They works as well. I need to redirect all `http` protocol requests to `https`. Here is the config of the apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName lamtakam.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =lamtakam.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.lamtakam.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =lamtakam.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.lamtakam.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/myweb>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any idea how can I make that redirection? Currently some cases works as expected and that redirection happens. The only domain that redirection doesn't happen for it is:

- http://www.lamtakam.com/questions

---

Noted that this doesn't work: *(however not sure if I place it correctly in the configuration)*

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?lamtakam\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 2):

This used to work but is [not recommended](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) as of somewhere in 2010 even. So don't use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?lamtakam\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Those would have been added to `.htaccess`.

You should be using this (from the same link):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.examples.com
    Redirect / https://www.examples.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.examples.com
    # ... SSL 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still the website is loaded on `http` protocol http://www.lamtakam.com/questions *(not secure)*

Comment: I don't see a  <VirtualHost *:443> in your question. Is there one? Cuz if there was not before you added mine... you need a lot more lines in that VirtualHost.  Your in the question is not for SSL ...

Comment: well no, I don't have `<VirtualHost *:443>`.  Since I don't know what should I write inside it (instead of `# ... SSL `). I just added `Redirect / https://lamtakam.com/` in the first `<VirtualHost *:80>`, and also I added `Redirect / https://www.lamtakam.com/` in the second  `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: Also I guess no need to `<VirtualHost *:443>` in the apache configuration. You know, I use [letsencrypt](https://certbot.eff.org/) and it will add all needed things automatically